# How to change something inside an switch statement?

Tags: xna, c#, menu

So my question is how would you draw a list of strings, and then if a case of the enum is a certain way, then draw them a different way? Here is an example of what I mean:

```
enum CurrentState
{
    Menu1,
    SubMenu1,
    SubMenu2
}
private CurrentState _currentState = CurrentState.Menu1;
public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch, GameTime gameTime)
{
    //Draw list here so it is always displayed in all cases
    switch (_currentState)
    {
        case CurrentState.Menu1:
        {
            //How would you erase the previous list and draw it in a different way here?
        } break;
        case CurrentState.SubMenu1:
        {
            //How would you erase the previous list and draw it in a different way here?
        } break;
        case CurrentState.SubMenu2:
        {
            //How would you erase the previous list and draw it in a different way here?
        } break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This question isn't very clear...are you asking how to draw text on the screen using `SpriteBatch`?  Or are you asking something to do with the logic of the state machine?  Because the code you posted seems to already answer your question...you just have to plug in the code for each submenu in each case of the `switch` statement.

Comment: You probably would just erase before the switch and redraw to the selection. Is this not possible?

Comment: How would you erase a for loop that is drawing a list?

Comment: Nevermind I just added an if statement and a bool to "erase" it if it isn't true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Don't draw the default list first**. If you want an "in all cases" use `default` as part of the `switch` functionality. The `default` case is triggered whenever none of the cases match.

```
switch (_currentState)
{
    case CurrentState.Menu1:
    {
        //Draw menu1
    } break;

    case CurrentState.SubMenu1:
    {
        //Draw submenu1
    } break;

    case CurrentState.SubMenu2:
    {
        //Draw submenu2
    } break;

    default:
    {
       //Draw list here so it is always displayed in all cases
    }
}
```